# Rotate a pixelated picture

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation, image

Do you have a formula or a function to rotate a pixelated picture in Matlab, which is represented as a matrix?

I don't want to use any photo editor.

Comment: What's so wrong with this question that I get a -1 for it?

Comment: Because a simple google search for "Matlab Rotate Matrix" would quickly reveal the answer. Stackoverflow isn't a replacement for the documentation or google.

Comment: Already did, had the wrong key-words, thank you, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/286903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not read the entire thread that you are linking to in your own answer, but if you have the Image Processing Toolbox then you can use `imrotate`.

http://www.mathworks.se/help/toolbox/images/ref/imrotate.html.